# Unable to initialize a variable in while in C#, why?

Tags: c#, while-loop

In C#, I can't initialize a variable in `while` statement, ie:

I can write this:

```
DataObject nextObject;
while((nextObject = ReadNextFile())!=null)
{
   //do something
}
```

But I can't do this:

```
while((var nextObject = ReadNextFile())!=null)
{
   //do something
}
```

To me, the latter is more readable than the former, so why it is not supported?

Comment: It's because [features are unimplemented by default](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/features-are-unimplemented-by-default/).

Comment: You can't initialize something in a while condition. It would initialize something in every loop.

Comment: @Apuna12: which is exactly what OP wants. You could also declare a variable inside of the loop and initialize it on every iteration. But it's not allowed to do it in the while-expression. The language designers could make it possible, but i guess they decided that this feature isn't missed enough to justify the costs to implement it.

Comment: Why would you need to initialize something in while condition? I think that the first option in the question is ok.

Comment: @Apuna12: it's ok and it works. But it's not as readable and compact as the second version. Other languages support it, C# not. VB.NET doesn't even allow to initialize the variable in the while-condition.

Comment: @Rango I don't really know why, but this is not very possible in C#